# Report viewer Tool for IOs?

Tags: ios, ipad, printing, report, viewer

I am trying to print a table containing data from an IOs app, I have already tested succesfully the phonegap printer plugin (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/iPhone/PrintPlugin/READEME.md) but i have some problems when I try to print several pages. Does anybody knows if there is a report viewer like Crystal or iReport available for IOs? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Report Runner Web Portal? It runs Crystal Reports on any device, and looks great on mobile devices. See it @ http://reportrunner.com